# How to create PostgreSQL user for Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I created a postgres user and database via this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# create database mydb;
postgres=# create user myuser with encrypted password 'mypass';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database mydb to myuser;
```

And I have this test script:

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
// pools will use environment variables
// for connection information
const pool = new Pool()
pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})
```

And I run this command:

```
PGHOST=localhost PGUSER=myuser PGDATABASE=mydb PGPASSWORD=mypass PGPORT=5432 node test-db.js
```

And there's no ouput, no error or NOW().

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser <username>;
sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>;
```

this commands is for create user database and create database .
then to ensure changes run this command
`\du` , `\du+`
that shows all users in postgres

Comment: @ryan Was your question solved with my answer?